# How to prevent chrome from creating a lockfile in the user data folder?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

I'm trying to run multiple instances of chrome driver through selenium with python. I'm successful with a single instance loading my default user profile, but running a second instance with the same user profile doesn't work because of what I assume is chrome creating a lockfile in my user profile folder. Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Make the folder readonly. Just kidding. I don't think preventing that lock file to be written is a clever idea - Chrome does this to ensure that no two processes are writing to the same history/storage database (to prevent data corruption). As far as I know there should be already an issue (too lazy to look up, please do that on your own) at the Chrome driver project that should add the functionality to select individual profiles for individual instances.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to use my default profile for each instance but never thought to just create copies of it. I'll toy around, but I think that'll do the trick for what I'm going for